# How add vertical line with title date in anychart in angular?

Tags: anychart

I add a vertical line but I want add title bottom with date position, in a candlestick, in the documentation not exist a textValue or titleValue

```
  plot
          .annotations()
          .startDrawing('vertical-line')
          .stroke('#446AAD80')
          .fill('#446AAD80')
```

Comment: Please provide the complete chart code to recreate the problem. 
You can utilize the AnyChart Playground to provide a demo with the recreated problem.

https://playground.anychart.com/

After that, we will be able to proceed with your query.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.